# How to set up .sublimelinterrc to ignore pep8 errors

Tags: sublimetext3, pep8, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text 3, and I'm trying to customize SublimeLinter-pep8 beyond the global (user preferences) level.  I have a file that has a lot of tabs in it, so error W191 shows up a lot.  As a test, I want to ignore this error.  If I add an `"ignore": "W191"` to the SublimeLinter.sublime-settings file, the error is ignored.  If I add it anywhere above the user level in the [settings stack](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/settings.html#settings-stack), the error is not ignored.

This is the linting part of my SublimeLinter.sublime-settings file.  If I add "W191" to the "ignore" section, that's the only time the error will be ignored by the linter.  Also, I noticed that `"max-line-length": null`, but I'm still getting max-line-length errors, so there may be something here beyond what I'm asking in this question.

```
    "lint_mode": "background",
    "linters": {
        "pep8": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore": "",
            "max-line-length": null,
            "select": ""
        }
    },
```

This is the entire contents of my .sublimelinterrc file.  I have it in the parent folder of my .py file (I've also tried putting it in the same folder).  It does not do anything.

```
{
    "SublimeLinter":
    {
        "@python": 2.7,
        "linters":
        {
            "pep8":
            {
                "ignore": "W191"
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

I have also tried adding this inline statement at the beginning of the .py file.  It also does not do anything.
`# [SublimeLinter pep8-ignore:+W191]`

I messed around with the Project settings, too, but I'm not sure how projects work in Sublime Text so I'm not sure whether I'm seeing the same issue or I just set it up wrong.

Debug mode doesn't show any warnings or errors about pep8, and it reliably re-lints every time I modify any of these files.  I would like to use .sublimelinterrc for this if possible, so that's what I'm mainly focusing on.  What am I missing?  Is there a setting I'm overlooking?  Am I putting the file in the wrong directory or something?

Comment: Your question is specific to the pep8 linter, so I wont add this as an aswer:  I use pylint and I set: disable=W0511, C0321, C0111, C0301, W0142, W1202 under [MESSAGES CONTROL] in ~/.pylintrc. Wfm.  However I also have issues adding disable messages inline to locally disable a warning.